# Working with IRC protocol, is it possible to know if the user who sent the message is voice or op?

Tags: c#, network-programming, client-server, protocols, irc

I am using the C# library [SmartIrc4net](https://github.com/meebey/SmartIrc4net) for creating an IRC bot.

when parsing a `PRIVMSG` message received from the chat server in IRC (this is generic, not specific to my library choice), is there any way to know if the user is a Voice or Op?

I have access to many fields like nick, message and such but I see no way of distinguishing a normal user from a voice or op...is that feasible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are receiving a PRIVMSG, you might want to distinguish in which channel the users has to be an operator or a voiced user.

You might want to check [ChannelUser](http://smartirc4net.meebey.net/docs/0.4.0/html/) class, which contains the methods isOp and isVoice

Comment: Thank you. I suspected that I would have to rely on other functions to list users...too bad I can't infer it only from the message data!

Comment: would you be kind enough to provide some form of pseudo-code, you know for which functions to call in which order, or after which events...Thanks!